# How to find if the elements of a vector alternate as sign?

Tags: c++

I tried to write a piece of code to find if the elements of vector are alternating and I count this in order to display. Help me a little bit!

```
int main(){
int n;
int temp;
vector<int> v;
int c=0;

cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>temp;
        v.push_back(temp);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<v.size();i++){

        if( (v[i]>0 && v[i+1]<0) || (v[i]<0 && v[i+1]>0) ){

            c++;
        }

    }
cout<<c;
```

Input:

16

1 -5 -3 2 -1 7 -2 5 1 -7 -9 0 -1 6 -1 -8

Output:

6

-3 2 -1 7 -2 5

Comment: What is wrong with the code you are showing?  Please [edit] your question to contain a [mre]

Comment: `v[i+1]` is undefined behavior, when `i = v.size () - 1`, due to indexing `v` out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are (at least) two problems with your code:

1. You access beyond the vector due to `[i+1]`. Change the loop to stop at `v.size()-1`
2. You don't handle the value zero correct. Change `>` to `>=`

But why not use the c++ algorithm library for this?

> How to find if the elements of a vector alternate as sign?

`std::adjacent_find` can help. Use it like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool alternating_sign(std::vector<int>& v)
{
    auto it = std::adjacent_find(v.begin(), v.end(), 
        [](const int& a, const int& b){return ((a<0 && b<0) || (a>=0 && b>=0));});
    return (it == v.end());
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1, -2, 3, -4, 1, 5, -2};
    std::vector<int> v2 = {1, -2, 3, -4, 1, -2};
    std::cout << "Test v1: ";
    std::cout << (alternating_sign(v1) ? "sign alternating" : "sign not alternating") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Test v2: ";
    std::cout << (alternating_sign(v2) ? "sign alternating" : "sign not alternating") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Test v1: sign not alternating
Test v2: sign alternating
```

The code looks for two adjacent elements that have same sign. If such two elements are found, you know that the sign isn't alternating.